# Div Background Image repeating on laptop display but not on external monitor

Tags: html, css

I've got a div with a background image I'm using for a hero image on my website. On my external monitor it fits perfectly and displays correctly.

When I drag the window over to my laptop display the background image is shifted over to the right. I've tried setting background size to cover but this just makes the image repeat.

The div is set to the width and height of the image (1920 x 600) and both screens are set to 1920x1080 resolution.

Is it because my laptop screen has a higher dpi? What should I change to get the image to display correctly on both screens? Would I need to have more than one image?

**Edit:** 
Here's how it looks on my external monitor (correct) 
[image]

And here's how it looks on the laptop (when i did the screen grab it was actually bigger than the original image size?)

[image]

Here's my CSS for the div

```
.hero-image {
 background-color: #679da7;
 background-image: url("../images/hero-image.png");
 height: 600px;
 }
```

Using background-size: contain / cover doesn't help, it just makes the image repeat on my laptop screen.

**Edit 2:**
Joe's solution worked. After a bit more googling it seems that despite my laptop display saying it's 1920 x 1080, it's actually only 1535px wide, which is why the image wasn't displaying correctly (it's wider than the screen) - *facepalm*

Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Could you please provide your css?

Comment: I've added my CSS for the hero-image div.

Comment: I see, you probably just need something like `background-position: right; background-repeat: no-repeat;`

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks Joe. Did a bit more googling and it seems my laptop display is only 1535px wide, despite it saying the resolution is 1920 x 1080. This is why the image was being pushed right, it was overflowing out the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the position and repeat rules:

```
background-position: right;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

on your background-image.

Answer (score 0):

What is the resolution of your monitor and laptop ?

Comment: both at 1920x1080. I suspect maybe the laptop screen is a higher dpi maybe and that's what's causing the issue?

Comment: Yes ! Set no repeat for background image should work.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
background-size : 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

on your div background

Comment: it will stretch image

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS3's background-size so that the image always fits in any container without being stretched.

```
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
background-image: no-repeat;
```

In using background size property, make sure that you set your background image property like this:

```
background-image: url('path/to/img');
```

instead of

```
background: url('path/to/img');
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the wanted result (not clear in question) you can do two ways.

**1) This will keep the image within the div, if the height is heigher than the div, It will leave a empty space there, use a background-color to see it more clear**

```
background-size: contain; 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

**2) this will always cover the full width and height of the div**

```
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

Joe's comment on my question worked. I also found out my laptop screen is only 1535 wide despite being at a resolution of 1920.

Thanks all.